# Can anyone recommend a way to check if a class can be serialized as XML?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I have a Generic class that takes an object of type T, serializes it as XML, then saves it to the filesystem. Currently however the serialize operation fails if the object is not serializable. That's not a problem as such, however I think it would be better to check in my class constructor whether an instance of T is serializable or not and if it is not, throw an error at that point rather than later on.

Is there a way of checking of an instance of T can be serialized as XML other than simply instantiating it and trying to serialize it in a TRY...CATCH? It would be nice if I could interrogate the class T in some manner to discover whether it can be serialized as XML or not.

If it helps, the code can be seen here: http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ac24e6e923cd#WinRtUtility%2fWinRtUtility%2fObjectStorageHelper.cs

Note that this code gets compiled against WinRT (i.e., it is for use in a Windows 8 app) however I think the question is relevant to any dialect of C#.

thanks in advance

Jamie

Comment: If you just want to check if the class is decorated with SerializableAttribte use typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SerializableAttribute), false)

Comment: Hi LeffeBrune, Thanks for the reply. No, I don't simply want to check that it has that attribute. My comments to some other replies hopefully explain why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, even if you check for various attributes (`Serializable`, `DataContract`) or check for the `Type.IsSerializable` (which I believe is just a convenience method for checking the `Serializable` attribute's existence) it doesn't guarantee that the implementation actually *is* serializable. *(EDIT: As mentioned, and seen in the example code provided in the question, `XmlSerializer` does not depend on the `Serializable` attribute adornment. So there's no sense in checking for these flags.)*

In my experience, your best bet is to use unit tests that will validate the various types used in your application and use try/catch to see if it pass/fails. At runtime, use try/catch (rather than pre-checking each time) and log/handle the exception.

If you have a list of valid compatible types as a result of your unit-testing, you can have a pre-check of `T` against a compile-time list that you determined from testing previously and assume any other types are just no good. Might want to watch for subclasses of known valid types though as even if they inherit from a valid serializable type, their implementation may not be.

EDIT: Since this is for Windows Phone 8, while I don't have experience with that platform, I have worked with Silverlight. And in that case, you can serialize objects even if they are not marked as `[Serializable]` (in fact, it doesn't even exist in Silverlight). The built-in `XmlSerializer` just works against all public properties regardless of adornment. The only way to see if it's serializable is either attempt a serialization and try/catch the failure, or write an algorithm to inspect each property (and recursively through child objects) and check if each type can be serialized.

EDITx2: Looking at your `ObjectStorageHelper`, I would suggest that you simply attempt serialization and catch any failures. You don't necessarily have to bubble up the exception directly. You could wrap with your own custom exception or have a returned results object that informs the API consumer of the pass/fail of the serialization and why it may have failed. Better to *assume* the caller is using a valid object rather than doing an expensive check each time.

EDITx3: Since you're doing a lot of other work in the save method, I would suggest rewriting your code like this:

```
public async Task SaveAsync(T Obj)
{
    if (Obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Obj");

    StorageFile file = null;
    StorageFolder folder = GetFolder(storageType);
    file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(FileName(Obj), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
    using (Stream outStream = Task.Run(() => writeStream.AsStreamForWrite()).Result)
    {
        try
        {
            serializer.Serialize(outStream, Obj);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            throw new TypeNotSerializableException(typeof(T), ex);
        }

        await outStream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

This way you catch the serialization issue *specifically* and can report to the API consumer very clearly that they have provided an invalid/non-serializable object. This way if you have an exception being thrown as part of your I/O portions, it's clearer where the issue is. In fact, you may want to separate out the serialization/deserialization aspects to their own discrete method/class so you can feed in other serializers (or be more clear from the stack trace where the issue is, or simply to make your methods do one thing and one thing only) But any more rewriting/refactoring is really left for code-review anyway and not valid much for the question at hand.

FYI, I also put a null check for your input object because if the user passes null, they would think that the save was successful when in fact, *nothing happened* and they might expect a value to be available for loading later when it *doesn't exist*. If you want to allow nulls as valid values, then don't bother with <s>the check</s> throwing an error.

Comment: Hi Chris,
Sounds like good advice however given that I want this to work for virtually any class T (this is a class library that I'm hoping will be used by others - I'm not actively using it to build an app) I don't really want to restrict only to a subset types that I have verified can be Serialized in my unit tests. Hope that makes sense.

JT

Comment: `Better to assume the caller is using a valid object rather than doing an expensive check each time.` Good advice +1

Comment: `XmlSerializer` does not require the `SerializableAttribute` to serialize and instance of a class.

Comment: @jamiet Totally does. See my latest "EDITx2". Essentially, put the onus on the consumers of your API to ensure their types are serializable. If they give you garbage, handle it and either bubble up the exception or report it to them however you want. Just document the serializable requirements (perhaps you can mention that you intend them to be compatible with `XmlSerializer` and point them to the appropriate MSDN doc)

Comment: P.S. Chris, not that it really matters but this is for Windows 8, not Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @jamiet Oops, misread. :) Advice still stands since you're using the `XmlSerializer` anyway.

Comment: "I would suggest that you simply attempt serialization and catch any failures" Yeah, that's pretty much what I'm doing now. In fact I have a unit test method (see HandleUnSerializableObject() at http://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/e695dad6ad5d#WinRtUtility%2fWinRtUtility.Test2%2fObjectStorageHelper.cs ) that checks for that. Guess I'll simply carry on doing what I'm doing already. Thank you all.

Comment: @jamiet Sadly you are in a bit of a catch-22 situation, see "Vexing Exceptions" in this article for another example. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: @jamiet That's good to have a unit test with a POCO. If you wish, you may consider adding a test with a POCO that contains child POCOs (to test non-struct/mutable properties). As for your error handling, I would suggest that you wrap the `serializer.Serialize(outStream, Obj);` line specifically with try/catch for `InvalidOperationException` to catch _only_ a serialization error and throw your own custom `TypeNotSerializable` exception (with type info, inner exception). Since you're doing other work (such as file I/O) those should be handled (or unhandled) separately.

Comment: @jamiet I added one final edit where I took my above comment into practice and modified your method slightly. I would definitely get rid of the empty `try/catch{throw}` that you have and just let the exception bubble up naturally (unless you want it there as a convenience debugging breakpoint?)

Comment: Wow, fantastic feedback. Thank you Chris. I'll review your comments later on (hopefully today) when I next sit down to work on this (I have an agreement with the wife for one evening a week on pet projects and I've already burned it up this week )

Comment: Hi Chris,I've just been looking at implementing some of your code recommendations. Turns out the try...catch around the serialization isn't really required because the serializer handles this sort of thing itself. "new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))" will throw a NotSupportedException. I HAVE implemented some of your suggestions around null checking tho.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what "can be serialized" means.  Any class can be serialized with `XmlSerializer`.  If what you mean by can be serialized is that no error occurs, then you'll have to try and catch exceptions to tell for sure.

Comment: Hi Peter
Yes, I guess what I actually meant is "can be serialized with no error occurring". As I alluded above I figured try...catch would be the only way to know for sure and you have pretty much just confirmed that. thanks. JT

Comment: Not all, XmlSerializer does not support circular references and interfaces.

Comment: @Huusom Right, and the only way to find that out is to try to serialize the type and catch any exceptions...